# Create a new csv file with the column name using multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-3.7

I am new to the python. Here, I have the following csv file which looks like ,

```
Prediction           per_RFC    per_JAPE

     100             100    97.37
    4600             100    86.15
    2200              80      80
    2900             100     100
    160              100     1.36
    3600             100      0
    2000             100      0
```

I have the features column like

```
feat_cols =[100,  156,  160,  162,  200,  256,  262,  2000,  2200,   2600,  2900,3600,4600]
```

Here, I  am trying to get a csv which looks like

```
100  156  160  162  200  256  262  2000  2200   2600  2900       3600     4600
100       100                      100    80           100       100       100
```

So , I am trying to add the values from the csv in this file

can any one help me with this ?

thanks.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: Yes sure I will add that as well

Comment: @dcg actually I tried but its a very wrong way so. could u please give a bit of hint or something ?

Answer (score 2):

To generate a DataFrame containing your expected content, run:

```
df2 = df.set_index('Prediction').per_RFC.reindex(feat_cols, fill_value='')\
    .reset_index().T
```

Then, to save it to a CSV file, run:

```
df2.to_csv('output.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

If you want the content saved just as you wrote (withot commas and with
spaces between columns), you can:

- generate a text variable: `tt = df2.to_string(header=False, index=False)`,
- save it to an ouptut file.